# Convert Global Space 3D Location to Local object space?

Tags: matrix, coordinates, projection, spaces

I'm trying to find a formula that could convert my 3D global coordinates into local object space.

Here are the inputs I have

```
A Location

B Location
B Rotation
B Scale
```

I need a Location output, corresponding to my A Location in B Space, according to B Location, Rotation, and Scale. I'm working in a 3D Space

So far I didn't found any formulas online, anyone can point me in the right direction?
Bests

If possible, i'd need a formula that doesn't use any matrix calculation, it's not supported by the nodal system of my engine (I'm using blender geometry node, but my problem is more generic as you can see)

Comment: What representation(s) can you use for B's rotation? Can you get it as a quaternion or angle-axis pair? Euler angles are a bit messy to invert.

Comment: Euler unfortunately ( in degrees)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll have to unpeel the transformations applied to B one by one, in reverse order. Typically we'll apply transformations in the sequence...

1. Scale
2. Euler Roll
3. Euler Pitch
4. Euler Yaw
5. Translate

So going backwards from 5 back to 1 (and assuming the {yaw, pitch, roll} axes are {z, x, y} - I'm not super familiar with Blender's conventions so you might need to swap some):

```
Untranslated = A.Location - B.Location

Unyawed = Yaw(Untranslated, -B.Rotation.z)

Unpitched = Pitch(Unyawed, -B.Rotation.x)

Unrolled = Roll(Unpitched, -B.Rotation.y)

Unscaled = Scale(Unrolled, (1/B.Scale.x, 1/B.Scale.y, 1/B.Scale.z) )
```

Now `Unscaled` is the point in B's local coordinate space that corresponds to the point A in the global coordinate space.

Here's how we can implement those rotation and scale functions:

(If your sine and cosine functions take their input in radians, be sure to convert your degree inputs to radians first)

```
Yaw(point, angle) {
    s = sin(angle)
    c = cos(angle)

    return (point.x * c - point.y * s, 
            point.y * c + point.x * s,
            point.z)
}

Pitch(point, angle) {
    s = sin(angle)
    c = cos(angle)

    return (point.x, 
            point.y * c - point.z * s, 
            point.z * c + point.y * s)
}

Roll(point, angle) {
    s = sin(angle)
    c = cos(angle)

    return (point.x * c + point.z * s,
            point.y,
            point.z * c - point.x * s)
}

Scale(point, scaleTriplet) {
    return (point.x * scaleTriplet.x,
            point.y * scaleTriplet.y,
            point.z * scaleTriplet.z)
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer,
How does Rotate() and Scale() translate to mathematical calculation?

Comment: You have access to a "transform point" node that takes Euler angle and scale triplet inputs, no?

Comment: Unfortunately no, i only have some vector math, or Float math nodes at my disposal,
That's why I'm currently searching for a "raw" formula, with no matrix formulas

Comment: I've added some potential implementations in pseudocode above.

Comment: Though I'll note, if you have access to vector math nodes like dot products, you can implement any matrix-based solutions you've found too. A matrix multiplication is just a set of dot products, taking the rows (or columns) of the matrix as vectors.